# Where can I download Biblatex? - a complete novice

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am a complete novice latex and I am currently learning how to create the bibliography. The tutorial I am looking at is https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/biblatex/

It tells me to use the bibtex but I cannot find a site in google where I can download the program. Could anyone recommend a website I can download the bibtex?

Comment: If you installed LaTeX already `biblatex` is either already installed on your system, or it can be installed using your TeX distribution. If you have installed TeX live, you can use `tlmgr install biblatex`, `tlmgr install Biber`. If you use MikTeX, go to the 'MikTeX Package Manager' or 'MikTeX Package Manager (Admin)' and install (using only one of the two) the package `biblatex` and the package you can find if you search for `biber`.

Comment: You just changed some instances of `biblatex` in your question to BibTeX? Do you want to use `biblatex` or BibTeX. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864)

Comment: If you are a complete novice, note that `biblatex` is a system for LaTeX (for the most part) to make bibliographies it is not a replacement for a proper LaTeX installation. It is basically a LaTeX package and a support programme.

Comment: I can't even distinguish between biblatex and bibtex... I have installed texlive so it has biber in it. I will find the difference between biblatex, bibtex and biber...

Comment: You'll definitely want to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864

Comment: I found out that my tex live contains biber in it, so I clicked the biber icon but it doesn't work... the screen keeps disappearing immediately. What is wrong?

Comment: Biber like BibTeX (and indeed pdfLaTeX and friends) is a command line tool. You need to start it from the command line. Often your editor can do that for you. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Maybe you should read a good introduction to TeX/LaTeX in general and then https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 (and indeed the tutorials linked there) for `biblatex` specifically.

Comment: Any news here? Did you get anywhere?

Comment: I finally managed to find a way to make citations. Thank you for your helps.